# Issue in the inserting text in the model to database on Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am new in the "Zend Framework". So I ran into some problems.

First of them is inserting text into database. e.g. i am inserting something like this **" what's happening"** and in the view appears **"what\'s happening now"** and symbol **" \' "** appears there.

Second, submiting text to controller like this(with html encoded symbols) "whats  happening" and only "whats" reaches the controller.

Please help me to solve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

There is an old PHP feature called magic quotes where PHP would automatically escape any post/get data to make it 'easy' to insert into a database. See http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php. It is likely to be this that is adding the quotes to your content. This feature has been deprecated, so I would recommend disabling it in your php.ini file (or htaccess) which should solve your problem. Assuming you are using mod_php, just add this to a .htaccess file:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

ZF will automatically escape content on insertion (assuming you are using Zend_Db correctly), so the issue you're having is because the data is being escaped twice.

Can you provide a little more info about your second question, e.g. how you are submitting the text and how you are using it in the controller?

Comment: How i can disable deprecated feature in the htaccess?

Comment: About my second question, there are html encoded symbols(like &nbsp;,&#163... ) in the body of the text. When i submit text to the controller only a part of it(till the first appearance of "&#163;") is reaching action. e.g. "Please help&#163; me to solve&#163; this problems?" --> "Please help".

Comment: I've added an example of how do disable magic quotes in htaccess. So for the second question you have this content in a form, and you're posting that to another page? If you `var_dump($_POST);` on that page do you see the full string there?

Comment: i have put "php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off" in the beginning of the .htaccess but i am getting error http status 500(Internal server error). `code`RewriteEngine On
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`code`

Comment: Check the Apache error log, it should show the cause of the error

Answer (score -2):

I never used ZF, but I can tell you the which functions you need to study for sanitizing the input/output

> During insertion into database

- [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)
- [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

> During display on Browser

- [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)
- [`htmlspecialchar()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
- [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)
- [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: Why was this down voted?  the only difference between mysql_real_escape_string() and addslashes() is for GBK and Big-5 char sets.  Otherwise you will get the same results (as far as SQL injection, etc is concerned), ESP for UTF-8.  BUT mysql_real_escape_string() requires a full RT to the database adding lots of unnecessary latency.

Comment: If you are using ZF never use the here mentioned functions! ZF and its Db-Classes will do this automatically for you, if you are using it correctly. That's the intention of an Database-Wrapper.